# How to activate layout tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for Layout tab for chrome dev tools. I was looking everywhere and can't find it. If it's extension or just in settings...watch img for better idea what I mean

[image: Layout Tab]

Comment: is this pic is firefox?

Comment: @RaghulShree Yes.

Comment: chrome dev tools don't have this feature yet brother.but firefox have but that doesn't mean Firefox is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in Google Chrome Devtools as of June, 2019.